# How to continue project in new file in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a large population survey dataset for a project and the first step is to make exclusions and have a final dataset for analyses. To organize my work, I must continue my work in a new file where I derive survey variables correctly. Is there a command used to continue work by saving all the previous data and code to the new file?

Comment: `saveHistory("outfilename")` to save the code you typed https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/savehistory.html, and `save.image("outfilename")` to save data http://rfunction.com/archives/420

Answer (score 0):

I don´t think I understand the problem you have. You can always create multiple .R files and split the code among them as you wish, and you can also arrange those files as you see fit in the file system (group them in the same folder with informative names and comments, etc...).

As for the data side of the problem, you can load your data into R, make any changes / filters needed, and then save it to another file with one of the billions of functions to write stuff to the disk: write.table() from base, fwrite() from data.table (which can be MUCH faster), etc...

I feel that my answer is way too obvious. When you say "project" you mean "something I have to get done" or the actual projects that you can create in rstudio. If it´s the first, then I think I have covered it. If it´s the second, I never got to use that feature so I am not going to be able to help :(

Maybe you can elaborate a bit more.